# Remove seconds from some observations to work in HM format using R

Tags: r, time, seconds

I have a column called "time" with some observations in "hours: minutes: seconds" and others only with "hours: minutes". I would like to remove the seconds and be left with only hours and minutes.
So far I have loaded the `lubridate` package and tried:

```
format(data$time ,format = "%H:%M")
```

but no change occurs.

And with:

```
data$time <- hm(data$time)
```

all the observations with h:m:s become NAs

What should I do?

Comment: You problem most probably comes from failing a) to understand that applying a function does not change its arguments UNLESS you assign the values back, and b) not being clear about what you intended to do with the results.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` to bring time into `POSIXct` format and then use `format` to keep the information that you need.

```
data <- data.frame(time = c('10:04:00', '14:00', '15:00', '12:34:56'))
data$time1 <- format(lubridate::parse_date_time(x, c('HMS', 'HM')), '%H:%M')
data

#      time time1
#1 10:04:00 10:04
#2    14:00 14:00
#3    15:00 15:00
#4 12:34:56 12:34
```

Comment: It would be most helpful to make a clear distinction between the different classes of these columns. A formatted result may not have the same behavior as a datetime column.