# Convert time in R?

Tags: r

Consider 9 hours from 8:00(am) to 5:00(pm). Set 0 for 8:00(am) and 9 for 5:00(pm).
If we have a vector `x` as follows:

```r
x = c(
0.03634568,0.47838162,0.80789109,0.99359959,1.02569362,1.55938143,
1.59509855,1.61406989,1.75217236,1.90665327,2.83467797,3.36134548,
3.93938312,4.06451236,4.38345992,4.47065016,4.70323660,4.81384233,
4.81655127,5.13904842,5.22296245,5.24547047,5.76230279,5.90503986,
6.59671006,7.03660356,7.35381102,8.79155176
)
```

How can we convert `x` to normal time format, e.g. 0.5 means 8:30(am) and 8.5 for 4:30(pm) or 16:30?

I have tried via [Convert time from numeric to time format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043140/convert-time-from-numeric-to-time-format-in-r)
as

```r
library(chron)
substr(times(x),1,5) #To strip off the seconds
# format(as.POSIXct((x) * 86400, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"), "%H:%M")
```

but it doesnt give the desired results. Any help?

Comment: If you use standard R date time class there is the possibility of calculating differences from a particular time, in this case 8:00A

Comment: @IRTFM I'm afraid I cannot get your meaning,  and tks any way for reply!

Comment: `lubridate::as_datetime("1970-01-01 08:00:00") + dhours(x)`?

Comment: @Limey It's great and nearly what I want! How can we just keep the time value vector like `y=c(08:02:10,08:28:42,08:48:28,08:59:36,09:01:32,09:33:33,09:35:42,09:36:50,09:45:07,09:54:23,10:50:04,11:21:40,11:56:21,12:03:52,12:23:00,12:28:14,12:42:11,12:48:49,12:48:59,13:08:20,13:13:22,13:14:43,13:45:44,13:54:18,14:35:48,15:02:11,15:21:13,16:47:29)`  without `1970-01-01` and something else?

Comment: @Limey Btw, I find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003657/converting-numbers-to-time which I have tried and tested `library(chron);  times( ( (x+8) / 60 ) / 24 )`  giving  `00:08:02 00:08:29 00:08:48 00:09:00 00:09:02 00:09:34 00:09:36 00:09:37 00:09:45 00:09:54 00:10:50 00:11:22 00:11:56 00:12:04 00:12:23 00:12:28 00:12:42 00:12:49 00:12:49 00:13:08 00:13:13 00:13:15 00:13:46 00:13:54 00:14:36 00:15:02 00:15:21 00:16:47 `  that gets very close to your results except the first `00:` and no-seconds showing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact task, `hms` can be quite convenient:

```r
x = c(
  0.03634568,0.47838162,0.80789109,0.99359959,1.02569362,1.55938143,
  1.59509855,1.61406989,1.75217236,1.90665327,2.83467797,3.36134548,
  3.93938312,4.06451236,4.38345992,4.47065016,4.70323660,4.81384233,
  4.81655127,5.13904842,5.22296245,5.24547047,5.76230279,5.90503986,
  6.59671006,7.03660356,7.35381102,8.79155176
)

library(hms)
tibble::tibble(
  hms_   = as_hms(hms(hours = 8) + x*60*60),
  round_ = as_hms(hms(hours = 8) + x*60*60) |> round_hms(secs = 1),
  trunc_ = as_hms(hms(hours = 8) + x*60*60) |> trunc_hms(secs = 1)
)
#> # A tibble: 28 × 3
#>    hms_            round_   trunc_  
#>    <time>          <time>   <time>  
#>  1 08:02:10.844448 08:02:11 08:02:10
#>  2 08:28:42.173832 08:28:42 08:28:42
#>  3 08:48:28.407924 08:48:28 08:48:28
#>  4 08:59:36.958524 08:59:37 08:59:36
#>  5 09:01:32.497032 09:01:32 09:01:32
#>  6 09:33:33.773148 09:33:34 09:33:33
#>  7 09:35:42.354780 09:35:42 09:35:42
#>  8 09:36:50.651604 09:36:51 09:36:50
#>  9 09:45:07.820496 09:45:08 09:45:07
#> 10 09:54:23.951772 09:54:24 09:54:23
#> # ℹ 18 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: What a great tidy style solution!  I remove seconds from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961872/remove-seconds-from-some-observations-to-work-in-hm-format-using-r via `as_hms(hms(hours = 8) + x*60*60) |> trunc_hms(secs = 1) -> y; format(lubridate::parse_date_time(y, c('HMS', 'HM')), '%H:%M')`,  showing `"08:02" "08:28" "08:48" "08:59" "09:01" "09:33" "09:35" "09:36" "09:45" "09:54" "10:50" "11:21" "11:56" "12:03" "12:23" "12:28" "12:42" "12:48" "12:48" "13:08" "13:13" "13:14" "13:45" "13:54" "14:35" "15:02" "15:21" "16:47"` @margusl

Answer (score 2):

Calculating modulo and integerize interim results.

```
h <- as.integer(x)
m <- as.integer((x %% 1)*60)
s <- as.integer((((x %% 1)*60) %% 1)*60)
sprintf('%02g:%02g:%02g', h, m, s)
#  [1] "00:02:10" "00:28:42" "00:48:28" "00:59:36" "01:01:32" "01:33:33" "01:35:42" "01:36:50" "01:45:07"
# [10] "01:54:23" "02:50:04" "03:21:40" "03:56:21" "04:03:52" "04:23:00" "04:28:14" "04:42:11" "04:48:49"
# [19] "04:48:59" "05:08:20" "05:13:22" "05:14:43" "05:45:44" "05:54:18" "06:35:48" "07:02:11" "07:21:13"
# [28] "08:47:29"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c(0.03634568, 0.47838162, 0.80789109, 0.99359959, 1.02569362, 
1.55938143, 1.59509855, 1.61406989, 1.75217236, 1.90665327, 2.83467797, 
3.36134548, 3.93938312, 4.06451236, 4.38345992, 4.47065016, 4.7032366, 
4.81384233, 4.81655127, 5.13904842, 5.22296245, 5.24547047, 5.76230279, 
5.90503986, 6.59671006, 7.03660356, 7.35381102, 8.79155176)
```

Comment: Tks for reply! Your solution with `h <- as.integer(x)+8` works for me, which showing `"08:02:10" "08:28:42" "08:48:28" "08:59:36" "09:01:32" "09:33:33" "09:35:42" "09:36:50" "09:45:07" "09:54:23" "10:50:04" "11:21:40" "11:56:21" "12:03:52" "12:23:00" "12:28:14" "12:42:11" "12:48:49" "12:48:59" "13:08:20" "13:13:22" "13:14:43" "13:45:44" "13:54:18" "14:35:48" "15:02:11" "15:21:13" "16:47:29" ` @jay.sf

Comment: @JohnStone I see, it's like adjusting for a time zone, right?